# Hibernate One to Many Annotation between user Entity and Address Entity, in the Address table I don't have the association with user id

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have create the user Entity which has a list of Addresses (@OneToMany annotation in user entity) and (@ManyToOne annotation in the Address Entity)

the user and address are well created but the I didn't get the association by the user id in the data base.

[image]

in the addresses Table I have the column **users_id** null
[image]

this my Request from insomnia:
[image]

**User Entity:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userEntity" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<AdressesEntity> adresses ;
```

**Address Entity**

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
private UserEntity userEntity;
```

**My Controoler :**

```
@PostMapping(
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
        )
public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> CreatUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest) 
        throws Exception {
            if(userRequest.getFirstName().isEmpty()) {
                throw new UserException(ErrorMessages.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD.getErrorMessage());
            }
            
            //UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            //BeanUtils.copyProperties(userRequest, userDto);
            ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
            UserDto userDto = modelMapper.map(userRequest, UserDto.class);
            
            UserDto createUser = userService.CreateUser(userDto);
            
            UserResponse userResponse = modelMapper.map(createUser, UserResponse.class);
    
            return   new ResponseEntity<UserResponse>(userResponse,HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

**Service Implementation of CreateUser(UserDto userDto) :**

```
@Override
public UserDto CreateUser(UserDto userDto) {
    // check exiting user
    UserEntity checkExisting_User = userRepository.findByEmail(userDto.getEmail());
    
    if (checkExisting_User != null)
        throw new RuntimeException("user already exist !");

    for (int i = 0; i < userDto.getAdresses().size(); i++) {

        AdresseDto address = userDto.getAdresses().get(i);
        address.setUserDto(userDto);
        address.setAdesseId(util.generatedValue(30));
        userDto.getAdresses().set(i, address);
    }
    
    userDto.getContact().setUser(userDto);
    userDto.getContact().setContactId(util.generatedValue(30));

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(userDto, UserEntity.class);

    userEntity.setEcryptyPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
    userEntity.setUserId(util.generatedValue(32));

    UserEntity newUser = userRepository.save(userEntity);

    UserDto userDto1 = modelMapper.map(newUser, UserDto.class);
    return userDto1;

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You must set the user on the address

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes I did it ( address.setUserDto(userDto); ) in service implementation I loop on List of address send it by the user and I try to assign the  the user for each object of address

Comment: Check if the UserEntity and it's associated AddressEntites all have the right relationships set before you call save

Comment: yes thanks the problem was in the model Mapper because I had named address in request and in AdresseDto I have adress .

Comment: Great. Please add this comment as the answer. It maybe helpful for someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace

@JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
@JoinColumn(name="users_id", referencedColumnName="id or user_id is depends what columns you can use")

Problem is you wrong create relationship on entity.

Or use
JoinColumn(name = "user_id")

I think is be helpfull.